# Conditional expectation: Kolmogorov’s Theorem question where the conditional being a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnzwG.png)

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vivce.png)

The question:

Fix $0<p=1-q<1$ reals, let $\Omega=\{0,1,2, \ldots\}$ be the non-negative integers, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ the power set, and $\mathbb{P}$ the probability measure that assigns $\mathbb{P}\{n\}=q^n p$ to $n \geq 0$. Define the function $X: \Omega \rightarrow\{0,1,2, \ldots\}$ to be the identity function. Notice that so far this is a way to describe a Pessimistic Geometric $(p)$ random variable (counting the failures before the first success). Define also
$$
Y:=(X \bmod 2)=\mathbb{1}\{X \text { is odd }\}= \begin{cases}0, & \text { if } X \text { is even } \\ 1, & \text { if } X \text { is odd }\end{cases}
$$
(a) What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ ?
(b) What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$ ?
(c) Use Kolmogorov's theorem on conditional expectations to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y)$.

Would someone be able to let me know if I'm on the right path with my answer for part c). I think I'm suppose to use the fact that the sigma algebra generated by X is a subset of the algebra generated by Y.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures

Comment: I don't think $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$, it must be the other way around. $\sigma(Y)$ is only genereated by $2$ sets and hence fairly small.

Comment: I was under the impression that $\sigma(X)$ only consisted of the empty set and $\omega$ as its the identity function.

Comment: @veganwithabeef You have 
$$ \sigma(X) = \sigma\left( \{X = k\} : k\in \mathbb{N]_0 \right) = \sigma(\{k\} : k \in \mathbb{N}_0) = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_0) $$

Comment: Ah, got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(\{2,4,6,\dots,\},\{1,3,5,\dots,\})$ you get
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=1_{X \text{ odd}}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X1_{X \text{ odd}}]}{\mathbb{P}(X \text{ odd})}+1_{X \text{ even}}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X1_{X \text{ even}}]}{\mathbb{P}(X \text{ even})}$$
And each of these quantities can simply be calculated.